# jsonschema 4.4.0 does not provide the extra 'isoduration'

Tags: python, jsonschema, kedro

So I'm trying to run some piece of code and keep getting the following error:

```
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 770, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'isoduration; extra == "format"' distribution was not found and is required by jsonschema
```

However, after running

```
pip uninstall -y jsonschema && pip install -U jsonschema && pip install jsonschema[isoduration]
```

I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema[isoduration] in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.4.0)
  WARNING: jsonschema 4.4.0 does not provide the extra 'isoduration'
```

and surely, running my code again I get the same error message as before.

**I tried:**

- `pip install isoduration`, but different format showed up as
  missing
- hard removing `jsonschema` with `rm -rf ...`
- installing `jsonschema==3.2.0` as it supposedly worked for a friend of mine

I'm very confused with what's going on here, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should install `isoduration`,

- https://pypi.org/project/isoduration/ ,

and/or use '`format`' install extra. From the [docs](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validate/?highlight=isoduration#validating-formats) (emphasis mine):

> There are a number of default checkers that FormatCheckers know how  to validate. Their names can be viewed by inspecting the FormatChecker.checkers attribute. **Certain checkers will only be available if an appropriate package is available for use.** The easiest way to ensure you have what is needed is to *install jsonschema using the `format` or `format-nongpl` setuptools extra* – i.e.
>
> ```
> $ pip install jsonschema[format]
> ```

Comment: I tried it, different format poped up as missing