# jupyter contrib nbextension install --user pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound webcolors and format-nongpl error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, command-line, anaconda, jupyter, anaconda3

First of all i installed jupyter

`conda install jupyter`

Then i installed nbextensions with the channel conda-forge

`conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

But when i entered the next command:

`jupyter contrib nbextension install --user`

Appeared a list of errors and it doesn´t run, the most important error was:

`pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'webcolors>=1.11; extra == "format-nongpl"' distribution was not found and is required by jsonschema`

Python version: `3.10.9`

I tried to install specific versions of jupyter and nbextensions but it doesn´t work anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the clue to make that works, in the installation of jupyter and jupyter contrib nbextension, it have happened some internal issue and it didn´t install some packages that nbextension needs to do the jupyter installation.

So i have had to install them:

`conda install -c conda-forge jsonschema-with-format-nongpl`

`conda install -c conda-forge webcolors`

Doing that and entering again that command, worked well.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are doing nbextension installation using pip and do not have conda installed. You can do the following.

Run the following command

```
pip install jsonschema[format]
```

And then run

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

And then hopefully you will be able to install nbextension without running into above error. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71857162/8329101) if you need more information on why this works.